# can a mvc custom html helper inherit a base helper?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, html-helper

So I want to be able to add a `data-` attribute to my `@HTML.Listbox` html helper in the razor syntax. My understanding is that I can't do this without creating my own customer html helper.

My question is, is there a way to create a custom html helper but basically inherit everything from the base `@HTML.Listbox` and then just add the ability to add a `data-` attribute? Does something like already exist?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Yes you can create your own `MyListBoxFor()` method(s) that calls the inbuilt `ListBoxFor()` method(s) and add additional values to the `htmlAttributes` parameter

Comment: I am not very comfortable with C# or mvc yet, would you possibly mind writing out a sample of what you mean exactly?

Comment: Its unclear why you would need to do this - why not just use `@Html.ListBoxFor(m => m.someProperty, Model.Options, new { data_someName = "someValue" })`

Comment: oh, does that work? haha i wouldnt use that because I didn't know that existed

Comment: Sure - that would generate `<select ..... data-somename="someValue">` - just ensure you use an underscore, not a hyphen (it will be converted to a hyphen by the method)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All the in-built `HtmlHelper` methods for generating form controls have overloads the allow you to add html attributes.

For the `ListBoxFor()` method, the [overloads are documented here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.selectextensions.listboxfor(v=vs.118).aspx). In your case its

```
@Html.ListBoxFor(m => m.someProperty, Model.Options, new { data_someName = "someValue" })
```

which will generate

```
<select name="someProperty" id="someProperty" multiple="multiple" data-someName="someValue"> .... </select>
```

Note when adding attributes containing a hyphen, you must use an underscore in the method (and the method will convert it to a hyphen in the rendered html).

You can also create your own `HtmlHelper` extension methods that can generate more complex html including automatically adding fixed attributes, for example you might create a `BootstrapTextBoxFor()` helper that automatically adds a `class="form-control"` attribute

```
public static MvcHtmlString BootstrapTextBoxFor<TModel, TValue>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> helper, 
Expression<Func<TModel, TValue>> expression, object htmlAttributes)
{
    IDictionary<string, object> attributes = HtmlHelper.AnonymousObjectToHtmlAttributes(htmlAttributes);
    attributes.Add("class", "form-control");
    ... other 'fixed' attributes as required
    return InputExtensions.TextBoxFor(helper, expression, attributes);
}
```

Some other example are shown in the the answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26162218/editortemplate-for-dropdownlist/26417466#26417466) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34913037/refactor-similar-chtml-that-renders-varying-properties-using-editorfor-and-label/34913933#34913933).

Answer (score 0):

Razor do the work for you:

```
@Html.AnythingHelperObject("NameOrId", new {data-yourcustomdatadom = "valueofdatadom"})
```

Comment: well i more meant how to write the actual `AnythingHelperObject` to return back the write htmlstring :) but yeah, razor rocks