# how to change default css class in @Html.EditorFor template

Tags: jquery, html, css, asp.net-mvc, razor

My viewmodel -

```
public class HashedArrayViewModel
    {
        [Required]
        [Display(Name = Constants.HashNameLabel)]
        public string HashName { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [Display(Name = Constants.HashColumnLabel)]
        public string HashColumn { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [Display(Name = Constants.HashAlgorithm)]
        public string HashAlgorithm { get; set; }
    }
```

in another view-model, I am referencing above class-

```
        [Required]
        [Display(Name = Constants.HashArrayLabel)]
        public HashedArrayViewModel HashColumns { get; set; }
```

My view-

```
 <div>
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.HashColumns, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
   @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.HashColumns, "", new { @class = "" })
 </div>
```

Generate markup -

```
 <div class="" id="hashcolumn" style="">
       <div>
    <div class="editor-label"><label for="HashColumns_HashName">Hash Name</label></div>
    <div class="editor-field"><input class="form-control text-box single-line" data-val="true" data-val-required="The Hash Name field is required." id="HashColumns_HashName" name="HashColumns.HashName" type="text" value=""> <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="HashColumns.HashName" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span></div>
    <div class="editor-label"><label for="HashColumns_HashColumn">Hash Columns</label></div>
    <div class="editor-field"><input class="form-control text-box single-line" data-val="true" data-val-required="The Hash Columns field is required." id="HashColumns_HashColumn" name="HashColumns.HashColumn" type="text" value=""> <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="HashColumns.HashColumn" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span></div>
    <div class="editor-label"><label for="HashColumns_HashAlgorithm">Hash Algorithm</label></div>
    <div class="editor-field"><input class="form-control text-box single-line" data-val="true" data-val-required="The Hash Algorithm field is required." id="HashColumns_HashAlgorithm" name="HashColumns.HashAlgorithm" type="text" value=""> <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="HashColumns.HashAlgorithm" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span></div>
     <span class="field-validation-valid " data-valmsg-for="HashColumns" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
       </div>
    </div>
```

and the page look like this - 
[image]

and if you notice in the above image, labels and fields are on the top of each other
my question is - 
how do I change the css classes on labels and fields. By default razor adds `editor-label` and `editor-field` respectively. I want to use  `col-md-10` and `col-md-10` .

Any other suggestion to fix the alignment is highly welcome.

Comment: [Write your own Editor template](http://bradwilson.typepad.com/blog/2009/10/aspnet-mvc-2-templates-part-4-custom-object-templates.html).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I created Editor templates under view/shared .

Answer (score 0):

The `EditorFor()` by default uses the `internal static string ObjectTemplate()` method defined in the [System.Web.Mvc.Html.DefaultEditorTemplates.cs](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetWebStack/blob/master/src/System.Web.Mvc/Html/DefaultEditorTemplates.cs)

To override the default, you need to create your own `EditorTemplate`. In the `/Views/Shared/EditorTemplates` folder, create a `HashedArrayViewModel.cshtml` partial (note the name of the template matches the name of the class), with the following code (add your class names and enclosing elements as required)

```
@model HashedArrayViewModel

@Html.LabelFor(m => m.HashName, new { @class = "..." })
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.HashName, new { @class = "..." })
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.HashName, new { @class = "..." })
.... // elements for other properties of HashedArrayViewModel
```

and in the view, use

```
@Html.EditorFor(m => m.HashColumns)
```

Note that your current `@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.HashColumns)` code makes no sense since `HashColumns` is a complex object and you cannot apply client side validation to a complex object.

Alternatively, you can write a custom `HtmlHelper` extension method that generates the label, input and validation message placeholder for each property as described in [Refactor similar CHTML that renders varying properties using EditorFor and LabelFor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34913037/refactor-similar-chtml-that-renders-varying-properties-using-editorfor-and-label/34913933#34913933), so that your can use

```
@Html.BootstrapEditorFor(m => m.HashName)
```

inside your `EditorTemplate`, or

```
@Html.BootstrapEditorFor(m => m.HashColumns.HashName)
```

in your main view